# Get a typesetted output of a macro back as a replacement text for another macro

Tags: macros

Let suppose you have a recursive TeX macro `\formula` (with inner control sequences advancing local counters), which once expanded and typsetted outputs an expression that meets all your needs: for instance an expression like f(x) (in a dvi output).

How to get this typesetted formula back as a return string of characters 
that you can use as a replacement "verbatim" text of another macro, 
such as `\def\secondformula{f(x)}`?

Here is as a MWE a definition of formula defining through recursion a Bessel function of the first kind of any order

```
\newcount\BesselOrder
\newcount\BesselOrderMinusOne

\def\BesselZERO{besj0(x)}
\def\BesselONE{besj1(x)}

\def\Recursion{%
\advance\BesselOrder by -1
\advance\BesselOrderMinusOne by -1
((2 * \the\BesselOrder / x) * {\BesselJ{\the\BesselOrder}} - \BesselJ{\the\BesselOrderMinusOne}) 
}

\def\BesselJ#1{%
    \BesselOrder=#1%
    \BesselOrderMinusOne = \BesselOrder%
    \advance\BesselOrderMinusOne by -1%
    \ifnum\BesselOrder = 0
        \let\next=\BesselZERO
    \fi
    \ifnum\BesselOrder = 1
        \let\next = \BesselONE
    \fi
    \ifnum\BesselOrder > 1 
        \let\next = \Recursion
    \fi
    \next
}
```

Comment: `\edef\secondformula{\formula}` might work if `\formula` is completely expandable. If it is only expandable to some degree, finer `\expandafter` precision might help. But if your `\formula` performs assignments you are usually out of luck since it won't be expandable. I'm sure I'm missing something here. Would it be possible to come up with a toy example that shows what you are trying to do (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)?

Comment: If this is only about the typeset output it might help to store the result in a box and reuse the box. `\newsavebox{\formulabox}\savebox{\formulabox}{\formula}\usebox{\formulabox}` Note that the code is executed once at the `\savebox` instruction and then 'frozen', i.e. every `\usebox` afterwards will result in the same output and no side-effects (until the box is overwritten with `\savebox`).

Comment: @moewe thank you  for your useful comments. I want to expand the expression of bessel functions of order n>0 through recursion. \formula is doing the work correctly but with assignments so it is not fully expandable as far as I understand your first answer.  I edit the post and show you as a MWE the \formula definition.

Comment: Ooops, sorry. I just added in the missing counter definitions almost at the same time when you edited the question, that made your modifications undone.

Comment: As far as I can see this definition is indeed not expandable. I'm also not sure if the boxes can help you here, since they usually are not context sensitive enough to allow for nice lines breaking and so are not suitable for longer contents. Another way would be to have `\BesselJ` assign the 'output' to a macro. It wouldn't be expandable itself, but you could re-use the output macro. I couldn't see an easy way to do that for this use case, though.

Comment: @moewe There should be a way to dump the typsetted output f(x) into an auxiliary  and temporary file that would contain \def\secondformula{f(x)} and could be re-used as \input. Would you know about a way to do this ?

Comment: The problem is that usually dumping to an auxiliary files expands commands more or less like `\edef` before writing, so that won't work here.

Comment: @moewe  I think we are stuck in some kind of a vicious circle :-). Thanks a lot very much for your explanations anyway, from which I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% This is to be compiled with e-TeX. (Not TeX and also not LaTeX.)

\overfullrule=0pt
\parindent=0ex
\parskip=\baselineskip
\begingroup\catcode`\%=12 \lowercase{\endgroup\def\percentchar{%}}%

% Pete's bessel-routine:
% ======================

\newcount\BesselOrder
\newcount\BesselOrderMinusOne

\def\BesselZERO{besj0(x)}
\def\BesselONE{besj1(x)}

\def\Recursion{%
\advance\BesselOrder by -1
\advance\BesselOrderMinusOne by -1
((2 * \the\BesselOrder/ x) * {\BesselJ{\the\BesselOrder}} - \BesselJ{\the\BesselOrderMinusOne})
}

\def\BesselJ#1{%
    \BesselOrder=#1%
    \BesselOrderMinusOne = \BesselOrder%
    \advance\BesselOrderMinusOne by -1%
    \ifnum\BesselOrder = 0
        \let\next=\BesselZERO
    \fi
    \ifnum\BesselOrder = 1
        \let\next = \BesselONE
    \fi
    \ifnum\BesselOrder > 1 
        \let\next = \Recursion
    \fi
    \next
}

% Ulrich's bessel-routine:
% ========================
%
% The routine doesn't need temporary assignments and the like and is based
% on expansion only.
% 
% !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
% !!!! Due to the \numexpr-thingie e-TeX-extensions are required. !!!!
% !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
%
% The routine as a trick for triggering expansion uses \romannumeral-expansion:
% When due to \romannumeral (La)TeX does gather together a sequence of digits
% trailed by a space as the number which it has to convert, expandable tokens
% get expanded.
% When in the end a number is gathered together which is not positive, as the result
% of the conversion (La)TeX will not deliver any token at all.
% Thus one can nicely (ab)use \romannumeral for triggering a lot of
% expansion-work and flipping-arguments-around-work as long as one ensures
% that in the end \romannumeral will not find a positive number.
%
% Due to \romannumeral-expansion \UDBesselJ will deliver the result in
% two expansion-steps/after "being hit" by two \expandafter .
%
% !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
% !!! \UDBesselJ will take its toll at the semantic nest and at the input-stack. !!!
% !!!                                                                            !!!
% !!! Don't use it with all too large values in the argument.                    !!!
% !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

\long\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}%
\long\def\passfirsttosecond#1#2{#2{#1}}%
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
\def\romannumeralstop{ }%

\def\UDBesselJ#1{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \ifnum#1 = 0 \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
  {\romannumeralstop besj0(x)}{%
    \ifnum#1 = 1 \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
    {\romannumeralstop besj1(x)}{%
      \ifnum#1 > 1 \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
      {%
        \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{%
          \romannumeral0%
          \exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
          \expandafter\UDBesselJ\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-2\relax}) %
        }{%
          \expandafter\passfirsttosecond\expandafter{%
            \romannumeral0%
            \exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
            \expandafter\UDBesselJ\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
          }%
          {\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}{\romannumeralstop((2 * }/ x) * } - %
        }%
      }{\romannumeralstop}%
    }%   
  }%
}%

% Testing the routines:
% =====================

{\tt\string\BesselJ\string{4\string}} yields:\hfil\break
\BesselJ{4}

\hbox to\hsize{\null\hrulefill\null}\nointerlineskip

{\tt\string\UDBesselJ\string{4\string}} yields:\hfil\break
\UDBesselJ{4}

\hbox to\hsize{\null\hrulefill\null}\nointerlineskip

{\tt\string\expandafter\string\expandafter\string\expandafter\string\def\hfil\break
\string\expandafter\string\expandafter\string\expandafter\string\secondformula\hfil\break
\string\expandafter\string\expandafter\string\expandafter\string{\percentchar\hfil\break
\string\UDBesselJ\string{4\string}\string}}

yields the macro
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\secondformula
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\UDBesselJ{4}}%
{\tt\string\secondformula:}

{\tt\meaning\secondformula}

\hbox to\hsize{\null\hrulefill\null}\nointerlineskip

{\tt\string\secondformula} yields:\hfil\break
\secondformula

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: @ Ulrich: Congratulations ! I have compiled your new definitions with pdfTeX flawlessly. Your mastering of the \romanumeral expansion process is really impressive to my unexperienced TeXnician eyes.

Comment: I need \second formula for both usage. But as long as \secondformula is an expanded  formula  that can be correctly lexically analyzed by the gnuplot software or by pgf+gnuplot tools everything should be ok.  So in this respect I would keep * as the multiplication sign and for the extra space near the closing parenthesis, this is not essential. Thanks a lot Ulrich for your wonderful routine.